# How to parse an HTML table, into a portable data-set; DSV, JSON, etc

Tags: python, csv, parsing, html-table, dataset

I'd like to capture all the data from an *[HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) table*, and place it into a data-set. Preferably, a *[DSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values)*, or a *[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)*.  Both of which, can be conveniently ported to other data-sets, and data-set containers, e.g., *[XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)*, or a *[database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)*.

The following *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)* article, contains a table of values I'd like to capture. *[Wikipedia – List of Solar System objects by size – Objects with radius over 400 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Solar_System_objects_by_size#Objects_with_radius_over_400_km)*.

I tried using *[XPath expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)*, and not only is the syntax complex, the task of relaying each *element* *class*, or *id*, is simply too daunting. Not to mention that *XPath* is intended for *XML*, and not *HTML*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Internet provides a wealth of data, that can be used by developers, and coders.
Capturing this data, although, is what proves trivial for most.  Considering, I find the task incredibly simple.

My general tools are, *[regular expression patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*, and *[scripting-languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)*.
I tend to avoid "[web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)", in the classical sense, e.g., using *[Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser))*, *[jsoup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsoup)*, etc.
For example, if you were to copy and paste an *HTML table* into a text-editor, you'd find the data to be delimited by *tab characters*.
This is much simpler to parse.

Although, to reiterate, feel free to provide a solution, using the like.

Start by picking a *[text-editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_text_editors)*, specifically one which provides a *find-and-replace* function, that allows for *regular expression patterns*.
Some examples are, *[Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)*, and *[SublimeText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text)*; even online tools, such as *regex101*, will suffice.
I will be using the *[IntelliJ IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)*, and a blank file.

Start by highlighting, and copying, the entire table; starting with the header text, "Body", up until the last column of the "2002 MS<sub>4</sub>" entry.
Paste the text into a new file.

If you quickly peruse the text, you'll find it contains several *notes* within brackets, e.g., "[123]", or "[abc]".
Use a *find-and-replace* to remove the values; here is a *pattern*.

```
\[.+?\]
```

Additionally, some of the numeric values contain commas.
Use a *find-and-replace* to remove these as well.

```
(?<=\d),(?=\d)
```

Some of the "Body" column entries have two lines of text.
We can use a *capture pattern* to bring this data onto the first line, and place it within parentheses.
Note, the "2002 MS<sub>4</sub>" required an accommodation; being more than one word.

```
(?s)^(\w+(?: MS4)?)$.+?^(.+?)(\t.+?)$
```

Replace this *match*, with the following specifiers.

```
$1 ($2)$3
```

Similarly, the "Radius", and "Type", columns have entries with multiple lines.
Although, there are only a few, we can do this manually.

As a final step, we'll need to adjust the first line; the headers.
The *HTML table* is using a *[column span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_cell#Colspan_and_rowspan)* attribute, so we'll need to move these sub-header values accordingly.
This can also be done manually.

```
Body    Image   Radius (km) Radius (R)    Volume (109 km3)    Volume (V)    Mass (1021 kg)  Mass (M)  Surface area (106 km2)  Surface area  Density (g/cm3) Gravity (m/s2)  Gravity ()    Type    Discovery
```

And, that is it for formatting.  We now have a *[TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values)* data-set.
This data can be pasted into a spread-sheet, or even parsed to a *[Python](https://docs.python.org/3/)* *[dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)*, or *JSON* set.

```
Body    Image   Radius (km) Radius (R)    Volume (109 km3)    Volume (V)    Mass (1021 kg)  Mass (M)  Surface area (106 km2)  Surface area  Density (g/cm3) Gravity (m/s2)  Gravity ()    Type    Discovery
Sun     695508 ± ?  109.2   1409300000  1301000 1989100000  333000  6078700 11918   1.409   274.0   27.94   G2V-class star  prehistoric
Jupiter     69911±6 10.97   1431280 1321    1898187±88  317.83  61419   120.41  1.3262±0.0003   24.79   2.528   gas giant planet; has rings prehistoric
Saturn      58232±6 (136775 for A Ring) 9.140   827130  764 568317±13   95.162  42612   83.54   0.6871±0.0002   10.44   1.065   gas giant planet; has rings prehistoric
Uranus      25362±7 3.981   68340   63.1    86813±4 14.536  8083.1  15.85   1.270±0.001 8.87    0.886   ice giant planet; has rings 1781
Neptune     24622±19    3.865   62540   57.7    102413±5    17.147  7618.3  14.94   1.638±0.004 11.15   1.137   ice giant planet; has rings 1846
Earth       6371.0084±0.0001    1   1083.21 1   5972.4±0.3  1   510.06447   1   5.5136±0.0003   9.81    1   terrestrial planet  prehistoric
Venus       6052±1  0.9499  928.43  0.857   4867.5±0.2  0.815   460.2   0.903   5.243±0.003 8.87    0.905   terrestrial planet  prehistoric
Mars        3389.5±0.2  0.5320  163.18  0.151   641.71±0.03 0.107   144.37  0.283   3.9341±0.0007   3.71    0.379   terrestrial planet  prehistoric
Ganymede (Jupiter III)      2634.1±0.3  0.4135  76.30   0.0704  148.2   0.0248  86.999  0.171   1.936   1.428   0.146   moon of Jupiter (icy)   1610
Titan (Saturn VI)       2574.73±0.09    0.4037  71.50   0.0658  134.5   0.0225  83.3054 0.163   1.880±0.004 1.354   0.138   moon of Saturn (icy)    1655
Mercury     2439.4±0.1  0.3829  60.83   0.0562  330.11±0.02 0.0553  74.797  0.147   5.4291±0.007    3.70    0.377   terrestrial planet  prehistoric
Callisto (Jupiter IV)       2410.3±1.5  0.3783  58.65   0.0541  107.6   0.018   73.005  0.143   1.834±0.003 1.23603 0.126   moon of Jupiter (icy)   1610
Io (Jupiter I)      1821.6±0.5  0.2859  25.32   0.0234  89.32   0.015   41.698  0.082   3.528±0.006 1.797   0.183   moon of Jupiter (terrestrial)   1610
Moon (Earth I)      1737.5±0.1  0.2727  21.958  0.0203  73.46   0.0123  37.937  0.074   3.344±0.005 1.625   0.166   moon of Earth (terrestrial) prehistoric
Europa (Jupiter II)     1560.8±0.5  0.2450  15.93   0.0147  48.00   0.008035    30.613  0.06    3.013±0.005 1.316   0.134   moon of Jupiter (terrestrial)   1610
Triton (Neptune I)      1353.4±0.9  0.2124  10.38   0.0096  21.39±0.03  0.003599    23.018  0.045   2.061   0.782   0.0797  moon of Neptune (icy)   1846
Pluto (134340)      1188.3±0.8  0.187   7.057   0.00651 13.03±0.03  0.0022  17.79   0.034   1.854±0.006 0.620   0.063   dwarf planet; plutino; multiple 1930
Eris (136199)       1163±6  0.1825  6.59    0.0061  16.6±0.2    0.0028  17  0.033   2.52±0.07   0.824   0.083   dwarf planet; SDO; binary   2003
Haumea (136108)     798±6 to 816    0.12    1.98    0.0018  4.01±0.04   0.00066 8.14    0.016   2.018   0.401   0.0409  dwarf planet; resonant KBO (7:12); trinary; has rings   2004
Titania (Uranus III)        788.9±1.8   0.1237  2.06    0.0019  3.40±0.06   0.00059 7.82    0.015   1.711±0.005 0.378   0.0385  moon of Uranus  1787
Rhea (Saturn V)     763.8±1.0   0.1199  1.87    0.0017  2.307   0.00039 7.34    0.014   1.236±0.005 0.26    0.027   moon of Saturn  1672
Oberon (Uranus IV)      761.4±2.6   0.1195  1.85    0.0017  3.08±0.09   0.0005  7.285   0.014   1.63±0.05   0.347   0.035   moon of Uranus  1787
Iapetus (Saturn VIII)       735.6±1.5   0.1153  1.66    0.0015  1.806   0.00033 6.8 0.013   1.088±0.013 0.223   0.0227  moon of Saturn  1671
Makemake (136472)       715+19−11   0.112   1.53    0.0014  ≈ 3.1   0.00053 6.4 0.013   ≈ 2.1   0.57    0.0581  dwarf planet; cubewano  2005
Gonggong (225088)       615±25  0.0983  1.03    0.0009  1.75±0.07   0.00029 4.753   0.009   1.72±0.16   0.3 0.0306  dwarf planet?; resonant SDO (3:10)  2007
Charon (Pluto I)        606.0±0.5   0.0951  0.932   0.0009  1.586±0.015 0.00025 4.578   0.009   1.70±0.02   0.288   0.0294  moon of Pluto   1978
Umbriel (Uranus II)     584.7±2.8   0.0918  0.837   0.0008  1.28±0.03   0.00020 4.3 0.008   1.39±0.16   0.234   0.024   moon of Uranus  1851
Ariel (Uranus I)        578.9±0.6   0.0909  0.813   0.0007  1.25±0.02   0.000226    4.211   0.008   1.66±0.15   0.269   0.027   moon of Uranus  1851
Dione (Saturn IV)       561.7±0.45  0.0881  0.741   0.0007  1.095   0.000183    3.965   0.008   1.478±0.003 0.232   0.0237  moon of Saturn  1684
Quaoar (50000)      543±2   0.0879  0.737   0.0007  1.20±0.05   0.0002  3.83    0.008   2.0±0.5 0.3 0.0306  cubewano; binary    2002
Tethys (Saturn III)     533.0±0.7   0.0834  0.624   0.0006  0.617   0.000103    3.57    0.007   0.984±0.003 0.145   0.015   moon of Saturn  1684
Sedna (90377)       498±40  0.0785  0.516   0.0005                              sednoid; detached object    2003
Ceres (1)       469.7±0.1   0.0742  0.433   0.0004  0.938   0.000157    2.85    0.006   2.17    0.28    0.029   dwarf planet; belt asteroid 1801
Orcus (90482)       455+25−20   0.0719  0.404   0.0004  0.548±0.010 0.000092            1.4±0.2 0.2 0.0204  plutino; binary 2004
Salacia (120347)        423±11  0.0664  0.3729  0.0003  0.492±0.007 0.000082            1.5±0.1 0.165   0.0168  cubewano; binary    2004
2002 MS4 (307261)       400±12  0.0628  0.2681  0.0002                              cubewano    2002
```

Here is an example parse, in *Python*.

```py
import csv as c
sso = {}
with open('wikipedia_sso.tsv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    r = c.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    next(it := iter(r))
    for (b, i, rkm, re, vkm3, ve, mkg, me, akm2, ae, d, ms2, ge, t, ds) in it:
        sso.update(
            {b: {'radius': {'km': rkm, 're': re},
                 'volume': {'km^3-10e9': vkm3, 've': ve},
                 'mass': {'kg-10e21': mkg, 'me': me},
                 'surface-area': {'km^2-10e6': akm2, 'e': ae},
                 'density': {'g/cm^3': d},
                 'gravity': {'m/s^2': ms2, 'e': ge},
                 'type': t,
                 'discovery': ds}})
```

```py
import pprint as p
p.pprint(sso['Earth'])
```

Output

```
{'density': {'g/cm^3': '5.5136±0.0003'},
 'discovery': 'prehistoric',
 'gravity': {'e': '1', 'm/s^2': '9.81'},
 'mass': {'kg-10e21': '5972.4±0.3', 'me': '1'},
 'radius': {'km': '6371.0084±0.0001', 're': '1'},
 'surface-area': {'e': '1', 'km^2-10e6': '510.06447'},
 'type': 'terrestrial planet',
 'volume': {'km^3-10e9': '1083.21', 've': '1'}}
```

And, here is a parse, from *Python*, to *JSON*.

```py
import json as j
print(j.dumps(sso['Earth'], sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Output

```
{
    "density": {
        "g/cm^3": "5.5136\u00b10.0003"
    },
    "discovery": "prehistoric",
    "gravity": {
        "e": "1",
        "m/s^2": "9.81"
    },
    "mass": {
        "kg-10e21": "5972.4\u00b10.3",
        "me": "1"
    },
    "radius": {
        "km": "6371.0084\u00b10.0001",
        "re": "1"
    },
    "surface-area": {
        "e": "1",
        "km^2-10e6": "510.06447"
    },
    "type": "terrestrial planet",
    "volume": {
        "km^3-10e9": "1083.21",
        "ve": "1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the easiest way to accomplish this is to read the whole page into pandas and then [save the appropriate dataframe to csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) or whatever:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Solar_System_objects_by_size#Objects_with_radius_over_400_km'
req = requests.get(url)

tables = pd.read_html(req.text)
```

your target table is

```
 tables[1]
```

Comment: Great, and to acquire the _requests_ and _pandas_ modules, is this a simple step?  I'm actually somewhat new to _Python_ coding.  I found a _pandas_ repository.

Comment: @Reilas - they are just python libraies - [you need to install them](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/).